# HTML5 Geolocation ignores enableHighAccuracy option?

Tags: javascript, android, html, geolocation

I am currently writing a webapp which is likely to be hit by mobile devices. At some point I need to retrieve the user's location, which I do by means of HTML5's getCurrentPosition(). I'd rather have a coarse fix as fast as possible, so I call this function with the enableHighAccuracy parameter set to false.

Most of the time this works as expected; however, on some Android devices browsers apparently ignore this attribute and always attempt to fetch the GPS location (the GPS icon appears on the notification bar). The funny thing is that this happens even if I manually disable GPS location in the Settings.

This doesn't seem to be browser-dependent, I have tested the same code with Chrome, Firefox and Opera, and happens with simple code such as the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getLocation() {

            if (navigator.geolocation)
            {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onLocationReceived, onLocationError, {timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: false});
            }
            else
                alert("Geoloc not supported by your browser");
        }

        function onLocationReceived(position) {
            alert("Location retreived! " + position.coords.latitude + ", " + position.coords.longitude + " (" + position.coords.accuracy + ")");

        }

        function onLocationError(error) {
            alert("Received an error! " + error.message + "(" + error.code + ")");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="getLocation();">Get location</button>
</body>
```

So far this has happened on the HTC One and the Xiaomi 1S. Have you ever come across this issue? Maybe it's a known bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I experience the same thing on Android Lollipop and Chrome 43.
I was hoping that I could do getCurrentPosition without highAccuracy and at the same time launch watchPosition with highAccuracy enabled.

But no. Both calls return at same (late) time, with the same (GPS) results...

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1057076

http://www.hyam.net/blog/archives/1432